# Adobe Analytics 1.4 Segments API - Reuse existing segment while using the method segment.save

Tags: adobe-analytics

The API requests for the [segment.save](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/documentation/segments-1-4/r-save) method of the [Segments 1.4 API](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/documentation/segments-1-4/segments-api) seem well documented and I am able to create segments dinamically using the API. However, I would like to reuse some alredy existing segments in the definition of my new segments.

**Problem:**

In the documentation, I am not able to find the way to reuse an already created segment as part of a new segment definition. In the web overlay, I am able to do it by dragging my segment in the different containers, as shown in the image:

[image: Example of]

The structure is for me comprehensible (Definition >> Container >> Rule). In the Web Overlay, rule/s is/are assigned automatically after dragging the segment to the container. However, it seems that I cannot reproduce this using the API. My logic would say me, that following structure could be realistic, but of course, nothing is documented about this matter:

```
{
    ...
    "definition":{
         "container":{
            "type":"hits",
            "rules":[
               {
                  "segmentId":"s1111111111111111"
               },
               {
                  "segmentId":"s2222222222222222"
               }
            ]
         }
    }...
```

**Question:**

Has someone experience using the segment.save method and knows if it is possible (and how) to use already created segments in the definition?

Comment: I don't have experience using the segments api but it looks like there is a `Segments.Get` method. Maybe you can save what you did in the interface from your screenshot and then use `Segments.Get` to see how it is structured?

Comment: @CrayonViolent thanks for the info. Initially, I have ignored the get method because I didnt know that I can define which fields should the response have (standard was only name and ID), Your advice made me put more attention to the method and I discovered, that I can also require the definition of a segment to see how it is done. Unfortunatelly, it seems that rules have to been writen down, although segment name is given. The structure seems to be a simple nesting of containers. It would be usefull to write a function that saves the rules in a data.frame for easier reuse of them when needed.

Comment: @agustin were you able to update the segments already created?